# Laravel how to pass the name of the user when I sent the forgot password function

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to make my mail more detailed when the user has sent a forgot password reset link to his/her email. This is the sample of the picture when receiving a reset password link.

[image]

I want to add some details here that the Hello should be Hello! (user name here)

Here is the code that I added in my **SendsPasswordResetEmails.php**

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        $applicant_name = Applicant::where('email', $request->email)->get()->value('name');

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

and it should pass the data to **app\Notifications\ApplicantResetPasswordNotification.php**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->from('vcc3dummy@gmail.com', 'CCV3')
                ->greeting('Hello! Applicant Name') // Applicant name pass here
                ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password request for your account.')
                ->action('Click here to Reset Password', route('applicant.reset', $this->token))
                ->line('If you did not reset your password, no further action is required.');
}
```

Looking for help on how to pass the data or how to query it.
Would appreciate if someone could help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can pass it to `ApplicantResetPasswordNotification.php` while calling it. where you are calling this file??

Answer (score 6):

In your `ApplicationResetPasswordNotification.php` you can use the `$notifiable` variable as follows:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->from('vcc3dummy@gmail.com', 'CCV3')
                ->greeting('Hello!' . $notifiable->name) // Applicant name 
                ...
}
```

Please mark as answer if that works for you!

Comment: Just it, nothing to pass in constructor, however you can `dd($notifiable)` to print the object.

Thanks for this answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the another way to send the mail in laravel -
`Put that data you want to use/show in email template`.

```
 $data = [
              'email' => $email,
              'remember_token' => $remember_token,
              'name' => $applicant_name
         ];

Mail::send('emails/forgotmail', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
      $message->from('youremail@gmail.com');
      $message->to( $data['email'] )->subject('Forgot Password Link');
                    });
```

Where as '`email/forgotmail`' is in '`resources/views/email/forgotmail.blade.php`' that you have to create. So that here you can put your email template over here and make use of $data in it .

Comment: I am using the auth generated forgot password. So I will put that in my SendsPasswordResetEmails.php?

Comment: Yes, you put that auth's template in it.

Comment: Sorry.. my bad, SendsPasswordResetEmails.php is your controller right? In controller 'SendsPasswordResetEmails.php ' add mail send function and in views create 'emails/forgotmail' to put your email template.

Comment: Its okay :) thanks. btw in my forgot password the email is only being inputted so I would not get the name like I will have to create a function for that or use a query to get the name of the applicant.

Comment: yes, you have to query to get the name of the applicant by using of applicant's email.So that, you can pass it in array to make use of it in view template.

Comment: Can I had a chat with you? I already getting the name of the applicant who wants to reset password but I don't know how to pass it in my mail template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153080/discussion-between-suniti-yadav-and-jayz-de-vera).